# Request Form for Employment Certificates, etc

Tags: word-usage

I work in the HR department and I need to come up with a title for a request form; this form is filled out to issue mainly Employment Certificates but also other certificates such as Salary Certificates.

I have two options and I think the second one is the best.
Can you please give me some suggestions?

> Request Form for Employment and Other Certificates
>
> Request Form for Certificates (Employment and Others)

Comment: Both are fine.  There's not really much else to say.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are quite similar and work, but if you were to choose one, I'd prefer the second one.

The second one is slightly better, as it is clearer that the main thing you are issuing is *certificates*, and you state in brackets that it can be employment certificates or others, which is slightly more clear than the first one.

But otherwise, they are the same and you can use either.